# Questions with links for SEO 'domain authority' from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, downvote-reason, seo

I'm wondering if an initial response and/or downvote for new questions on Stack Overflow should take into account whether the poster seems to be creating an outbound link to their website for SEO purposes.

I've encountered enough questions that aren't duplicates, and seem to meet enough criteria to be a (barely, sometimes) legitimate question. But their general lack of substance, the nature of the website, and the fact that they provide an "example" of their (often trivial) problem by linking to something like "seoservices.com" or "awsumsoftwaredevs.com", etc. makes it seem likely it's just an attempt to get a backlink to their website from Stack Overflow, which would have great "domain authority".

I know this is something that's gone on since the dawn of Stack Overflow. And I'm not judging whether it's a good SEO strategy or validating the underlying concept.

**Is it fair game to take this into account when voting on a new question? Does it even matter from the perspective of filtering out low-quality questions or should it just be overlooked?**

Comment: eh, i suggest ignoring such links. If that link not existing makes the question unclear or off topic, vote accordingly. You shouldn't assume malice

Comment: I believe SO adds `rel="nofollow"` to all links in posts, so there would be no SEO gain, from my little understanding of SEO.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I know nothing of this domain. I'd like someone who does know more than the two of us about it to also chip in here. It seems like knowing this technical bit could dictate most of the conversation here. Now where could we find a community of people that know something about SEO...

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Not sure if this is a rhetoric question (as questions asking for SEO advice are off-topic on Stack Overflow), but for people interested in SEO, we have a Stack Exchange site: [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know it's a cliché to quote xkcd, but I'm reminded of this comic:

[image: xkcd #810: Constructive]

I think in most cases it's possible to separate the *motive* for a post from the *quality* of that post. If someone is posting *low quality* questions or answers in order to publicise their site, then that is no different from them posting low quality questions or answers for any other reason. If they are posting *high quality* questions and answers, then it is not up to you to determine their motivation for doing so.

On the other hand, there is the question of the links themselves: if a link has no bearing on the question, it should be edited out; if the link is to a commercial service without appropriate disclosure, it is spam.

As pointed out in the comments, anyone doing this to obtain higher ratings in search engines will likely be disappointed, because like most user-editable content, questions and answers here are marked with ["nofollow" metadata telling search engines not to give such credit](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en).

Finally, remember that *for really clear-cut cases*, you can flag content as Spam (assuming you have sufficient reputation). An approved spam flag does more than just delete the post; it trains filters to look for similar posts, and it penalises the user who posted it, including internal measures beyond the normal reputation system.

Answer (score 11):

Links on Stack Overflow automatically have `rel="nofollow"`, which tells any SEO crawler that we don't want to pass reputation. That doesn't mean it won't pass any, however, and people who resort to spam to build SEO are typically of the "throw it against the wall and see if it sticks" sort anyway. There are SEO tricks that work today, but good luck a month down the road.

Understand that there are at least two groups that actively look at this stuff as it comes in, and most of it is flagged for removal one way or the other. I'd say the risk is minimal. Stack Overflow is a strong authority site and that won't change.